# Which file does API call go?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sorry for the basic question, but where does an API call go in swift (using Alamofire or session.dataTask)? Should I place this in a view controller or make a separate class with a method that calls the Api and then call that from my view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Separate your concerns for code reusability. If you think there is even the slightest chance that the API call you are creating can be used in another file at some time, put it in its own file. I usually create API client classes that are as loosely coupled from the rest of the project as I can manage. It makes for easier reuse, easier updates, and easier debugging. There is no shame in having files with very few lines of code if you can justify it.

Also, think of view controllers as a way to display and interact with a GUI. If you are writing something in a view controller that doesn't have to do with one of those two concerns, it might not be well placed there.

Comment: Thank you! I am struggling to find out where code should go, some tutorials cram it all in the VC and some make separate files for everything, but what you said will help me greatly!